# Bind data from source under xaml designer

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-8

I am using a split page view for one of my page layouts in my Windows 8 app. If I run the app in debug mode the source details are loaded and everything is fine.

However, in my XAML designer view I am unable to bind the data to the view using d:Source &  d:DataContext even though I've defined the xmlns:data source.

The error I get is as follows: The name "MyDataSource" does not exist in the namespace "using:MyApp.Data"

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: A few more Information would be great. Please post relevant xaml with namespace-usings and binding expressions. Does your DataSource have a default c'tor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. Rookie mistake, I used the incorrect `namespace`. Instead of `MyApp.Data`, I used just `MyData` in defining the source file `namespace` model.